# Error when adding a new language (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error when trying to add multiple languages via get! I'm not good at using get because I'm a flutter beginner. But the error appeared only in this class! The error (as shown in the picture) appears when adding the word (.tr), Could it be because of the abstract class?

I didn't try much, but my attempts failed[[image: This is part of the code]]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.tr` is an extension, and the `stg` will change on runtime. Therefore `Text` widget can't be const. While `ScakBar`'s content using non-const `Text`(being `.tr`), `SnackBar` cant be const.

Remove the `const` on line 25.

Find more about [const](https://dart.dev/language/variables#final-and-const).

Comment: see [answer]. It is discouraged to answer problematic questions. See also [ask] for what a good question looks like.